# Issue with Highcharts pie charts with frameset

Tags: charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I am using highcharts pie charts. I am displaying 4 pie charts in single page with different series of data. It's working well and good. But if im using frameset and calling those pages inside that then these pie charts are not displaying, but if I move page forwared then backward then the charts are displaying. Kindly help to figure out this.

```
<?php
include('../control/config.php');
if($_REQUEST['basic']!=null)
{
    if($_REQUEST['basic']=='internal')
    {
        $basepage='internal.php';
    }
    if($_REQUEST['basic']=='external')
    {
        $basepage='index.php';
    }
}

$projectdir= '../data/project';
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its filename
if (is_dir($projectdir))
{
    if ($dh = opendir($projectdir))
    {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
            if($file!="." and $file!=".." and $file!=".svn")
            {
                $project_files[]=$file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}


if($_REQUEST['pie']!=null){

    if($_REQUEST['pie']==0){
    $pie1=0;
    $pie2=1;
    $pie3=2;
    $pie4=3;
    }
    if($_REQUEST['pie']==1){
    $pie1=4;
    $pie2=5;
    $pie3=6;
    $pie4=7;
    }
    if($_REQUEST['pie']==2){
    $pie1=8;
    $pie2=9;
    $pie3=10;
    $pie4=11;
    }
    if($_REQUEST['pie']==3){
    $pie1=12;
    $pie2=13;
    $pie3=14;
    $pie4=15;
    }


}
else{
$pie1=0;
$pie2=1;
$pie3=2;
$pie4=3;
}



$projectname1=explode('.',$project_files[$pie1]);
$projectname2=explode('.',$project_files[$pie2]);
$projectname3=explode('.',$project_files[$pie3]);
$projectname4=explode('.',$project_files[$pie4]);



    session_start();
    $_SESSION['piefilename1'] = '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie1];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['piefilename2'] = '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie2];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['piefilename3'] = '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie3];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['piefilename4'] = '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie4];


?>

<head>
<title>AFLS ISSUE SUMMARY</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="../style/default.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA="screen">
<script>
function go_to_url()
{
    document.location.href='<?php echo $base_path.$basepage;?>?pgco='+<?php echo $_REQUEST['pgco'];?>+'&pie='+<?php echo $_REQUEST['pie'];?>;
}
function timeGreeting()
{
    window.setTimeout(go_to_url, <?php echo $_REQUEST['seq'];?> );
    //milliseconds to load next page.
}
timeGreeting();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myfile='<?php echo $project_files[$pie1];?>';

        var options1 = {
                        chart: {
                                renderTo: 'container1',
                                defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
                                        spacingTop: 10,
                                        spacingBottom: 5,
                                        spacingLeft: 5,
                                        spacingRight: 5

                        },
                        title: {
                           text: '<?php echo $projectname1[0];?>'
                        },

                       plotOptions: {
                                      pie: {
                                      size:'74%',
                                          allowPointSelect: false,
                                          cursor: 'pointer',
                                          showInLegend: false,

                                          dataLabels: {
                                           rotation: 0,
                                          distance: 10,
                                              enabled: true,
                                              color: '#2f7ed8',

                                               formatter: function() {

                                             if(this.y == 0)
                                                                         return null
                                                                     else
                             return this.point.name  + ' [ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + ' ]';



                                }
                          }
                      }
            },
            legend: {
                        enabled: true,
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        width: 200,
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        useHTML: true,
                        borderWidth: 5,
                         borderRadius: 10,
                        labelFormatter: function() {
                            return '<div style="text-align: left; width:130px;">' + this.name + '</div><div style="width:40px; text-align:right;">' + this.y + '%</div>';
                        }
        },

                       series : []
                     };
                    var myfile='<?php echo '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie1];?>';
                    $.get(myfile,function(data) {
                                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split(';');
                var series = {
                                 dataLabels: {
                                            enabled: true,
                                           style: {
            color: '#000000',
            fontFamily: 'verdana',
            fontSize: '12px',

            lineHeight: '21px'


}},
                                        data: []
                };
                // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
              $.each(lines, function(lineNo,line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                    series.data.push({
                    type:'pie',
                    name: items[0],
                    y:parseFloat(items[1])
                 });
              });
              options1.series.push(series);
                // Create the chart
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options1);
            });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myfile='<?php echo '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie2];?>';
            var options2 = {
                        chart: {
                           renderTo: 'container2',
                           defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
                           spacingTop: 10,
                                                                spacingBottom: 5,
                                                                spacingLeft: 5,
                                        spacingRight: 5
                        },
                        title: {
                           text: '<?php echo $projectname2[0];?>'
                        },
                       plotOptions: {
                                      pie: {
                                          size:'74%',
                                          allowPointSelect: false,
                                          cursor: 'pointer',
                                          showInLegend: false,

                                          dataLabels: {
                                          rotation: 0,
                                              distance: 10,
                                              color: '#2f7ed8',

                                              enabled: true,
                                             formatter: function() {

                                                                                                                                     if(this.y == 0)
                                                                                                                                                                 return null
                                                                                                                                                             else
                                                                                                                        return this.point.name  + ' [ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + ' ]';
}
                                          }
                                      }
            },
                           colors: [
                              '#4572A7',
                              '#AA4643',
                              '#DB843D'
                           ],
                       series : []
                     };
                     $.get(myfile,function(data) {

                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split(';');
                var series = {
                 dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
            color: '#000000',
            fontFamily: 'verdana',
            fontSize: '12px',
            lineHeight: '21px'
}},
                        data: []
                };
                // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
              $.each(lines, function(lineNo,line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                    series.data.push({
                    type:'pie',
                    name: items[0],
                    y:parseFloat(items[1])
                 });
              });
              options2.series.push(series);
                // Create the chart
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options2);
            });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myfile='<?php echo '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie3];?>';

            var options3 = {
                        chart: {
                           renderTo: 'container3',
                           defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
                           spacingTop: 10,
                                                                spacingBottom: 5,
                                                                spacingLeft: 5,
                                        spacingRight: 5
                        },
                        title: {
                           text: '<?php echo $projectname3[0];?>'
                        },
                       plotOptions: {
                                      pie: {
                                          size:'74%',
                                          allowPointSelect: false,
                                          cursor: 'pointer',
                                          showInLegend: false,

                                          dataLabels: {
                                          rotation: 0,
                                              distance: 10,
                                              color: '#2f7ed8',

                                              enabled: true,
                                             formatter: function() {

                                                                                                                                     if(this.y == 0)
                                                                                                                                                                 return null
                                                                                                                                                             else
                                                                                                         return this.point.name  + ' [ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + ' ]';
                                                                                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
            },
                           colors: [
                              '#4572A7',
                              '#AA4643',
                              '#DB843D'
                           ],
                       series : []
                     };
                     $.get(myfile,function(data) {

                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split(';');
                var series = {
                 dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
            color: '#000000',
            fontFamily: 'verdana',
            fontSize: '12px',
            lineHeight: '21px'
}},
                        data: []
                };
                // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
              $.each(lines, function(lineNo,line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                    series.data.push({
                    type:'pie',
                    name: items[0],
                    y:parseFloat(items[1])
                 });
              });
              options3.series.push(series);
                // Create the chart
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options3);
            });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myfile='<?php echo '../data/project/'.$project_files[$pie4];?>';

            var options4 = {
                        chart: {
                           renderTo: 'container4',
                           defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
                           spacingTop: 10,
                                                                spacingBottom: 5,
                                                                spacingLeft: 5,
                                        spacingRight: 5
                        },
                        title: {
                           text: '<?php echo $projectname4[0];?>'
                        },
                       plotOptions: {
                                      pie: {
                                          size:'74%',
                                          allowPointSelect: false,
                                          cursor: 'pointer',
                                          showInLegend: false,

                                          dataLabels: {
                                          rotation: 0,
                                              distance: 10,
                                              color: '#2f7ed8',

                                              enabled: true,
                                               formatter: function() {

                                                                                         if(this.y == 0)
                                                                                                                     return null
                                                                                                                 else
                                                                      return this.point.name  + ' [ ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + ' ]';
}

                                          }
                                      }
            },
                           colors: [
                              '#4572A7',
                              '#AA4643',
                              '#DB843D'
                           ],
                       series : []
                     };
                     $.get(myfile,function(data) {

                // Split the lines
                var lines = data.split(';');
                var series = {
                 dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
            color: '#000000',
            fontFamily: 'verdana',
            fontSize: '12px',
            lineHeight: '21px'
}},
                        data: []
                };
                // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
              $.each(lines, function(lineNo,line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                    series.data.push({
                    type:'pie',
                    name: items[0],
                    y:parseFloat(items[1])
                 });
              });
              options4.series.push(series);
                // Create the chart
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options4);
            });
</script>


</head>
<body>

<?php include('header.php');?>




<table border='0' width='100%'>
<tr>
    <td width='50%' align='right' valign='top'>
      <?php include('pie1.php');?>
    </td>

<td width='50%' align='right' valign='top'>
  <?php include('pie2.php');?>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>
    <td width='50%' align='right' valign='top'>
      <?php include('pie3.php');?>
    </td>

<td width='50%' align='right' valign='top'>
  <?php include('pie4.php');?>
</td>

</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But when you load frameset, pages contains included all js scripts? Do you receinve any errors in console?

Comment: <HTML>
 <FRAMESET rows="97%, 3%">
  <FRAME src="index.php" scrolling="No" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">;
  <FRAME src="view/scroll.php" name="piechart" scrolling="No" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0" align="middle">;
 </FRAMESET>
</HTML>                                                              Index.php contains the 4 pie charts.This problem is happens only in ie. I am generating 4 pie charts dyanamically.the file sources are from csv files.i have also echo the file names and it is passing correctly

Comment: But I cannot reproduce this because you have many elements, but could you reproduce this issue in the jsfiddle.net? In simple way? Do you receive errors in console?

Comment: No i didnt receive any errors in console.as said earlier my webpage automatically goes to next page every 30 sec. so after moving to next page if i click back button then the charts displays. actually out of 4 pie charts in  a page i am checking for some php condition and if no data is available then i will not render for that particular pie and intead of that i will call a image in else part. whether using images may disturb the chart rendering?